# Setting a comment form on a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to set a comment form on a post in the "group message show" view.But I have an error message like,

NoMethodError at /group_messages/64
undefined method `group_message_group_message_comments_path' for #<#:0x007f9c0afa0b38>

Could you give me some advice?

☆show.html.erb(group_messages)

```
<h2>Add a comment</h2>
 <%= form_for([@group_message, @group_message_comment])  do |f| %>
  <% if @group_message_comment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@group_message_comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this group_message_comment from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
       <% @group_message_comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
       <li><%= msg %></li>
       <% end %><%# do%>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- error_explanation-->
  <% end %><%# if any?%>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :member_id %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :member_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :gmessage_id %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :group_message_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :group_id %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :group_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
  </div>
 <div class="actions" >
    <%= f.submit "Comment"%>
 </div>
<% end %><%# form_for>
```

☆group_messages_controller

```
def show
    if !checklogin? then return end
      @group_message = GroupMessage.find(params[:id])
      @isme = me? @group_message
      @group_message_comment = GroupMessageComment.new
      @group_message_comment = GroupMessage.find(params[:id]).group_message_comments.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @group_message }
    end
end
```

☆GroupMessage model

```
class GroupMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :member_id, :group_id

  belongs_to :member
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :group_message_comments

end
```

☆GroupMessageComment model

```
class GroupMessageComment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :gmessage_id, :group_id, :member_id

  belongs_to :member
  belongs_to :group_message

end
```

☆routes.rb

```
MiniSNS::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :group_message_comments


  root :to => 'members#login'
  match '/groups/join'
  resources :group_messages
  resources :groups do 
  resources :group_messages
  end
  match '/members/new'


  resources :index
  resources :groups
  post 'groups/:id' => 'group#show'
  post '/groups/new'
  post '/index/index'

  match '/members/login'
  match '/members/logout'
  match '/members/friend'
  match 'members/show'
  post 'messages/comment'

  resources :comments
  resources :messages
  resources :friends
  resources :members
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message is due to the following line of code:

```
<%= form_for([@group_message, @group_message_comment])  do |f| %>
```

This is because you haven't set the correct routing for your models. Can you post your routes.rb too so that I can have a look?

I think you need nested routes, something like:

```
resources :group_messages do
    resources :group_message_comment
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Hara Kang,I added routes.rb.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I solved it with the code below,

    resources :group_messages do
        resources :group_message_comments
    end